# Repeating (menu) background in HaxeFlixel?

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxeflixel

I've tried to load a 16x16 image as a `FlxSprite`, but I don't know how to make it repeat to span across the whole Window. How would I do that?

Where I load the sprite:

```
class MainMenuState extends FlxState {
  var _menuBg:FlxSprite;
  override public function create ():Void {
    _menuBg = new FlxSprite(16, 16, 'assets/img/block1_16.png');
    add(_menuBg);
    super.create();
 }

 override public function destroy ():Void {
   super.destroy();
 }

 override public function update ():Void {
   super.update();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FlxBackdrop` (from flixel-addons) for that.